# Regex to find all spaces in lines beginning with a specific string

Tags: regex, pcre

I am searching for a regex to find all the spaces in lines starting with a specific string (in a SVN dump file). Despite the "global" modifier my regex returns only the first occurence of the space character.

A part of the file i am working on :

```
...
pla bla bli

Node-path: branches/BU ILD/ml_cf/syst em/Translation/TranslationManager.class.php  
Node-kind: file
Node-action: change
Text-delta: true
....
```

The regex :

```
/Node-path: \S*(\ )/g
```

finds only the first space (between U and I) but not the others on the line.

Comment: I am searching for ALL the spaces on the line starting with "Node-path: "

Comment: You're searching for all incidences of `Node-path: \S*(\ )` on the line. There is only one.

Comment: Maybe it would help us understand the purpose for why you're searching for all spaces..?

Comment: Please explain what you need to do. I can tell you beforehand that finding all the spaces on a give line will return a list of spaces. If you want to know how many of them there are then use `tr/ //`

Comment: anubhava gave the good answer. Now i need to use a sed to replace all the instances of space returned by the regex by underscores. It seems that there are some espacing magic to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PCRE regex to find all the spaces on a line starting with a particular text, use this regex:

```
/(?:^Node-path: |\G)\S+\K\h+/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fH1tS2/2)

- Using `(?:Node-path: |\G)` we are matching lines starting with `Node-path:` OR positioning at the end of the previous match.
- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match
- `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match.
- `\h+` matches 1 or more of horizontal whitespace (space or tab)

Comment: Thank you! It does the job!

Comment: That is what i have done but my reputation is too low for my votes to change the publicly displayed score.